# Not able to play videos from assets folder using VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player, android-assets, mediacontroller

I am not able to play videos from assets folder using MediaController in VideoView.
I looked into many stack overflow answers but none of them work.
It works perfectly when I use Raw folder or SD Card folder path.

Below is my code :

```
    private void getVideoFromAssets() {

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                VideoViewActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/test.mp4");
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        // Close the progress bar and play the video
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            videoview.start();

        }
    });


}
```

This same code works for raw and sd card folder while changing the respective path.But it does not work with assets.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(fileName);
   player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
```

Comment: This uses MediaPlayer. But I use MediaController class.

Answer (score 1):

"file:///android_asset/..."  works only for a WebView, you need to pass a Uri like this "content://your.authority/path.to.resource" that is you need to create custom ContentProvider and override its openAssetFile

Comment: Thanks @pskink. Can you please provide an example for this.

Comment: example of how to extend some class and override one of its method?

Comment: Ok,I got it.Will try and let you know the output.